# Java Loop only running once

Tags: java, loops, boolean

Im building a code guessing game if you insert an invalid input ie( 333 ) it will prompt you to change your guess. however this only works on guess #1 on guess    #2 - #6 it will let any invalid input go through

```
public void game(){
    System.out.println("Enter guess #" + (guessAtt + 1));
    guess = keyboard.next();
    guess = guess.toLowerCase();
    if( guess.equals(quit)){
        System.exit(0);
    }   
    if (guess.length() < 2){
        System.out.println("Guess Too short try again");    
        game();     
    }
    if (guess.length() > 3){
        System.out.println("Guess too long try again");
        game();
    }
    letter1 = guess.charAt(0);
    letter2 = guess.charAt(1);
    letter3 = guess.charAt(2);
    isValid();

}
public boolean isValid(){


if (letter1.equals('a')|| letter1.equals('b')|| letter1.equals('c')|| letter1.equals('d')|| letter1.equals('e')){
      isValid1 = true;
}
if(letter2.equals('a')|| letter2.equals('b')|| letter2.equals('c')|| letter2.equals('d')|| letter2.equals('e')){
     isValid2 = true;
}
 if(letter3.equals('a')|| letter3.equals('b')|| letter3.equals('c')|| letter3.equals('d')|| letter3.equals('e')){
     isValid3 = true;   
}
if(isValid1 == true && isValid2 == true && isValid3 == true){
    isValid = true;
}
else {
     isValid = false;

}


while (isValid == false){
    System.out.println("invalid input try again\n");
    game();

}
return isValid;
}
```

Comment: There's no loop in the code you have provided.

Comment: Where is your loop ?

Comment: It seems that `game()` is called in a loop and OP didn't provide it.

Comment: Slight irony that it is a guessing game

Comment: I see some errors here as it is. OP calls `game()` if the `guess` is not exactly `3 char`s long, but does not `return` afterwards, so errors can be had.

Comment: OH. Hey OP, use `nextLine` instead of `next`, it may help you a bit.

Comment: Is it just me or is everyone missing the while-loop call in the `isValid()` method? (And the callback at the end of the `game()` method making it a double looped program)...

Answer (score 2):

you could both use a while loop in the game that breaks when isValid() returns a true. You could also call the function game if isValid() returns a false value. Now you ask for a boolean value, but you don't use it. No matter what it returns, as long as your value contains the right lenght, the game ends.